# Problem installing Tikz Feynman

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, tikz-feynman

I have to draw a couple of Feynman diagrams for my paper. I am using Overleaf. After placing `\usepackege{tikz-feynman}` in the preamble, it sais `tikz-Feynman not found`. My question is, how can I incorporate tikz-Feynman with Overleaf.

Comment: You will have to get in contact with Overleaf and ask them, to provide that package. If you have written it correctly and you are getting this error, they are not having that package on their system. Nothing we can help with, I fear.

Comment: Indeed the TeX Live distro on Overleaf doesn't have `tikz-feyman` yet. You can still use it, if you upload the tikz-feyman package files to your project using the "Add files" button at the top of your Overleaf project's file list. See for example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gztfscfhgnrh Click on the "open as template" button to view the file list.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, though quite understandably, Overleaf and ShareLaTeX are reluctant to update their TeXLive distribution too frequently in fear of possibly breaking things for everyone.  Since Ti*k*Z-Feynman is still quite a new package, it hasn't had time to make it to their servers yet.

Fortunately, LaTeX also searches for packages in the same directory as the main TeX file, so it is possible to upload TikZ-Feynman's file to your Overleaf/ShareLaTeX project and it should work fine.

You can download Ti*k*Z-Feynman either from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman), or from the [project site](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman), and then it is just a matter of uploading the files.  Not all files are required, and for v1.1.0 of Ti*k*Z-Feynman, the necessary files are:

```
tikzfeynman.keys.code.tex
tikzfeynman.patch.3.0.0.lua
tikzfeynman.patch.3.0.1.lua
tikz-feynman.sty
tikzlibraryfeynman.code.tex
```

For ShareLaTeX, there's a [template project](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/new/template?zipUrl=/project/571845e855374a8e523d7829/download/zip&templateName=TikZ-Feynman&compiler=lualatex) that sets up the necessary files and compiler.